# pass a data from kernel to user space

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, mapping, pass-by-reference, kernel-module

I'm currently writing a module for Linux, and I want to pass a queue of data from kernel to user space (my program in user responsible to read this data - and then responsible write those to a file), and my approach is to get a memory location in user space and push data from kernel to it.

How can I implement it?

Do you have a better approach? I'm Beginner, and any guides can be nice.

Before that, I try to push this data to user space with IOCTL and PROCFS but that approach is not a good idea and I lost some data.

Comment: Wrong way around. User space should initiate read from kernel buffer. Kernel is always running, but user processes can start and stop (and lose all allocated memory)

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to do so:

1. *sysFS*. You can use [sysFS API](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/sysfs.html) (using [kobjects](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kobject.txt)) to create a pseudo-file under `/sys` or other sysFS mount point like for procFS. The second is usually used for kernel built-in features, for kernel module you should use sysFS instead. [Tutorial](https://pradheepshrinivasan.github.io/2015/07/02/Creating-an-simple-sysfs/).
2. *procFS*. Similar to sysFS. You can use [procFS API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjqvZnqxtD7AhWILsAKHclqArEQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkernelnewbies.org%2FDocuments%2FKernel-Docbooks%3Faction%3DAttachFile%26do%3Dget%26target%3Dprocfs-guide_2.6.29.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0GKCffpUu6hNKqJp2PmJcN) to create a pseudo-file under `/proc` or other procFS mount point.
3. *DebugFS*. Similar, but a bit different. Usually used for debug purposes. [DebugFS API](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/debugfs.html).
4. *Netlink Sockets*. The preferred way to communicate to userspace if you'd like to communicate to only one or two programs, not everyone. [Tutorial](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356).
5. *ioctl*. May be used for many purposes, kinda "System Call". [Tutorial](https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x856.html).
6. *configFS*. like sysFS, but ram-based. [ConfigFS API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/configfs/configfs.txt).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use mmap. This system call will allow you to share a buffer between userspace and kernel space, avoiding the need to copy data.
Obviously, you will then need an out of band way of synchronizing where is the data that is ready to be read.